# Get ALL results of a word mapping with a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I got a word like this: `kfc`

Then a dictionary: `{'k':'1', 'c':'3'}`

How can I get a list like that?

`kfc, 1fc, kf3, 1f3`

It means there always will be `2^n` possibilities, with `n` is the number of dictionary's keys in that word.

P/s: All I can think is using recursive function, however, I prefer non-recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`.  For example, let's define the preliminaries:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = 'kfc'
>>> d = {'k':'1', 'c':'3'}
```

Now, let's compute the result:

```
>>> [ ''.join(x) for x in itertools.product( *[(c, d.get(c)) if d.get(c) else c for c in s] ) ]
['kfc', 'kf3', '1fc', '1f3']
```

#### How it works

First, we use list comprehension to get the posibilities that we need to consider:

```
>>> [(c, d.get(c)) if d.get(c) else c for c in s]
[('k', '1'), 'f', ('c', '3')]
```

In the above list comprehension, we iterate through each character `c` in string `s`.  For each `c`, we assemble the possibilities which are either `(c, d[c])` if `d[c]` exists or else just `c` if it doesn't.

Next, we use itertools to create all the possible products:

```
>>> list( itertools.product( *[(c, d.get(c)) if d.get(c) else c for c in s] ) )
[('k', 'f', 'c'), ('k', 'f', '3'), ('1', 'f', 'c'), ('1', 'f', '3')]
```

The above has the answers that we need.  We just need to re-assemble the strings using `''.join`:

```
>>> [ ''.join(x) for x in itertools.product( *[(c, d.get(c)) if d.get(c) else c for c in s] ) ]
['kfc', 'kf3', '1fc', '1f3']
```

Comment: @ John1024 But are there any ways to do this without using itertools.product? I mean use the recursive only

Comment: And whatif my dictionary is {'k':['1','2'], 'c': '3'}?

Comment: and could you explain the algorithm of itertools.product, in case I rewrite it in C/C++

Comment: @Chingchang I recursive solution is possible but, in the question, you stated _"I prefer non-recursive"_.  That is why I chose a non-recursive approach for the answer.  Separately, you do not have to translate the  `itertools.product` source code to C++.  It was written in C++ and the source code is available [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c?revision=76602&view=markup).